# JSON File not loading in

Tags: jquery, json

I'am trying to load in a json file, but it won't load in and it keeps giving a weird error: "TypeError: e is undefined".

I'm not sure if `$.each(data.Dishes) is correct or is it $.each(data.Dishes.Lunch)`
This is what I have right now in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lunch_section").empty();
    $(".diner_section").empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Menu.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.Dishes, function(index) {
                $('section.lunch_section').append("<h2 class='sectiontitel'> <span> Lunch </span> </h2><article class='Lunch_article'><img src='" + data.Dishes.Lunch[index].Image + "' alt='food_image'/>");
            });
        },

        // eventuele foutafhandeling....
        error: function() {
            alert("Houston, we have a problem");
        }
    });
});
```

This is how my json looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Dishes":
        [
            {
                "Lunch": 
                [
                    {
                        "Name":"Bento Box",
                        "type":"main",
                        "Image":"Images/lunch/Bento.jpg",
                        "description":"Bento is a single-portion takeout or home-packed meal common in Japanese cuisine. A traditional bento holds rice, fish or meat, with pickled or cooked vegetables, usually in a box-shaped container. Containers range from disposable mass produced to hand crafted lacquerware. Bento boxes are readily available in many places throughout Japan, including convenience stores, bento shops, railway stations, and department stores. However, Japanese homemakers often spend time and energy on a carefully prepared lunch box for their spouse, child, or themselves.",
                        "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento",
                        "ingredients": 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "no1":"Rice",
                                        "no2":"Fish",
                                        "no3":"Seaweed",
                                        "no4":"Soy Sause",
                                        "no5":"vegetables",
                                        "no6":"meat"
                                    }
                                ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Name":"Miso Soup",
                        "type":"entree",
                        "Image":"Images/lunch/miso.jpg",
                        "description":"Miso soup (misoshiru?) is a traditional Japanese soup consisting of a stock called \"dashi\" into which softened miso paste is mixed. Many ingredients are added depending on regional and seasonal recipes, and personal preference.",
                        "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miso_soup",
                        "ingredients": 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "no1":"Dashi",
                                        "no2":"Tofu",
                                        "no3":"Miso Paste"
                                    }
                                ]
                    }

                ],


                "Diner": 
                    [
                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Nigiri",
                            "type":"Nigiri",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/sake_nigiri.jpg",
                            "description":"Nigirizushi (\"hand-pressed sushi\") consists of an oblong mound of sushi rice that the chef presses into a small rectangular box between the palms of the hands, usually with a bit of wasabi, and a topping (the neta) draped over it. Neta are typically fish such as salmon, tuna or other seafood. Certain toppings are typically bound to the rice with a thin strip of nori, most commonly octopus (tako), freshwater eel (unagi), sea eel (anago), squid (ika), and sweet egg (tamago). One order of a given type of fish typically results in two pieces, while a sushi set (sampler dish) may contain only one piece of each topping",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Salmon",
                                            "no3":"Wasabi paste",
                                            "no4":"Soy Sause"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        },

                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Maki",
                            "type":"Maki",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/Sake_maki.jpg",
                            "description":"Makizushi (\"rolled sushi\"), norimaki (\"Nori roll\") or makimono (\"variety of rolls\") is a cylindrical piece, formed with the help of a bamboo mat known as a makisu. Makizushi is generally wrapped in nori (seaweed), but is occasionally wrapped in a thin omelette, soy paper, cucumber, or shiso (perilla) leaves. Makizushi is usually cut into six or eight pieces, which constitutes a single roll order. Below are some common types of makizushi, but many other kinds exist.",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Seaweed",
                                            "no3":"Salmon"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        },

                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Temaki",
                            "type":"Temaki",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/sake_temaki.jpg",
                            "description":"Temaki (\"hand roll\") is a large cone-shaped piece of nori on the outside and the ingredients spilling out the wide end. A typical temaki is about ten centimeters (4 in) long, and is eaten with fingers because it is too awkward to pick it up with chopsticks. For optimal taste and texture, temaki must be eaten quickly after being made because the nori cone soon absorbs moisture from the filling and loses its crispness, making it somewhat difficult to bite through. For this reason, the nori in pre-made or take-out temaki is sealed in plastic film which is removed immediately before eating.",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Salmon",
                                            "no3":"Wasabi paste",
                                            "no4":"Avocado",
                                            "no4":"Seaweed"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        } 

                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Edited:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url:        'Menu.json',
                dataType:   'json',
                success:    function(data)
                {                       
                    $.each(data[0].Dishes, function(index)
                    {
                        $('section.lunch_section').append("<h2 class='sectiontitel'> <span> Lunch </span> </h2><article class='Lunch_article'><img src='" 
                            + data[0].Dishes[0].Image
                            + "' alt='food_image'>");
                    });
                },

                // eventuele foutafhandeling....
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("Houston, we have a problem");
                }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON defines an **array** with one entry, which is an object with one property, `Dishes`, whose value is an array. So:

```
// Get first array entry
//         vvv
$.each(data[0].Dishes, function...
```

Answer (score -1):

try using $.parseJson(data) before trying to iterate with $.each